# net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 parameter marker not allowed

Tags: java, mysql, swing, ms-access, jdbc

I am new to ucanaccess. I am developing a java swing application, I am using MS Access 2016 to store my DB.I am trying to insert values into my table. I am using sql's insert into query. Everything seems right, but then I am getting error saying parameter marker not allowed (I think its referring to "?" which I used to pass variables to my query).

Here is the is the DB code:

```
public static void updateDB(String NOBOOKS, java.util.Date DOI, java.util.Date DOR){
    try{   
        Connection on = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://Database/UserDetails.accdb");
        Statement stmt = on.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Member";
        System.out.println(Uid);
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println(DOR);
        while(result.next()){
            if(Uid.equals(result.getString("ID"))){  
                String N = NOBOOKS;
                Date I = new Date(DOI.getTime());
                Date R = new Date(DOR.getTime());
                String sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO Member (Issues,DOI,DOR) VALUES (?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement values = on.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
                System.out.println("The DOI is "+ DOI);
                System.out.println("The I is "+ I);
                System.out.println("The DOR is "+ DOR);
                System.out.println("The R is "+R);

                values.setString(1, N);
                values.setDate(2, I);
                values.setDate(3, R);
                stmt.executeUpdate(sqlUpdate);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception se) {
        System.out.print(se);
    }   
}
```

and this is the output i am getting.

```
2
Tue Sep 20 00:00:00 IST 2016
The DOI is Mon Sep 05 00:00:00 IST 2016
The I is 2016-09-05
The DOR is Tue Sep 20 00:00:00 IST 2016
The R is 2016-09-20
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 parameter marker not allowedBUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 25 seconds)
```

Comment: If you use a PreparedStatement, you must call the executeUpdate method on this PreparedStatement  with no arguments: values.executeUpdate(). What you are doing instead doesn't make sense.

Comment: Got it!. @jamadei Thanks for the info :)